# How to get which fragment is active Android

Tags: android

I am using list fragments using custom adapter. I want to add messages dynamically to the list. So i want to find which fragment is active.

Comment: Please define what "active fragment" means in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` you can override `setPrimaryItem` which is called every-time a fragment is selected:

```
Fragment currentFragment;
@Override
public void setPrimaryItem(ViewGroup container, int position,
        Object object) {
    super.setPrimaryItem(container, position, object);
    currentFragment=(Fragment)object;
}
```